# What does it mean when SQL "Max" has a second (integer) parameter?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a question about a SQLite query that I am working with to grab data from a .db file in Python:

```
SELECT SUM(MaxSquence) FROM (SELECT MAX(SequenceNum,0) AS MaxSquence FROM attacheddb.Table1 WHERE...
```

(SequenceNum is an often low-value, single-digit, integer value)

My main confusion lies not in the specific interaction of the query with my code, but in the purpose of the 'MAX(SequenceNum, 0)' section. What is the purpose of the '0' after SequenceNumInTrack? Is it creating some kind of list that can be summed up with the SUM keyword earlier on in the query?

Comment: See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar) on the max() SQL function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the subquery, `MAX` is being used as a [scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar):

> The multi-argument max() function returns the argument with the maximum value, or return NULL if any argument is NULL. The multi-argument max() function searches its arguments from left to right for an argument that defines a collating function and uses that collating function for all string comparisons.

In particular, the call to `MAX(SequenceNum, 0)` will return a value which is greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

> SequenceNumInTrack is an often low-value (single-digits) integer value

This does not make sense if `SequenceNumInTrack` is never negative.

SQLite's [`MAX(X,Y,..)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar) scalar function returns the greatest value of its arguments.

In the case of `MAX(SequenceNum, 0)` if `SequenceNum`'s values are **always positive** (or `0`) then `MAX(SequenceNum, 0)` is equivalent to just `SequenceNum`.

If on the other hand **there are negative** values, then your code uses  `MAX()` to ignore these negative values for the upcoming `SUM()`.